# Angular 7 HttpClient POST - Bad request

Tags: post, symfony4, angular7

Taking again the tutorial of the site Angular, I created in winamp a database with a table including a field {"id": id, "name": name} and I make 2 queries on this table with Symfony4:
1) A request to list heroes.
2) A request to create hero.

Executed from Angular 7, the query 1) works perfectly (route / listerHeroes).

Executed from Angular 7, query 2) does not work, it returns error 405 (route / ajouterHero). However launched from Postman, this query works.

I can not find any documentation to explain to me this bug on which I stumble for several days. A track please
Below copy of both classes: heroes.service.ts and component3.component.ts

```
    // heroes.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { HttpErrorHandler, HandleError } from './http-error-handler.service';
import { Hero } from '../assets/Structure';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type':  'application/json'
  })
};

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class HeroesService {
  heroesUrl = 'http://heroes/';
  private handleError: HandleError;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, httpErrorHandler: HttpErrorHandler) {
    this.handleError = httpErrorHandler.createHandleError('HeroesService');
  }

  getHeroes$(): Observable<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get<Hero[]>(`${this.heroesUrl}listerHeroes`, httpOptions);
  }

  addHero(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> {
    return this.http
      .post<Hero>(`${this.heroesUrl}ajouterHero`, hero, httpOptions)
      .pipe(catchError(this.handleError('addHero', hero)));
  }
}

    // component3.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HeroesService } from '../heroes.service';
import { Hero } from '../../assets/Structure';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component3',
  templateUrl: './component3.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./component3.component.css']
})
export class Component3Component implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[];
  editHero: Hero;

  constructor(private heroesService: HeroesService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.heroesService.getHeroes$().subscribe(res => (this.heroes = res));
  }

  addHero(name: string): void {
    name = name.trim();
    console.log('FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF C3A name =', name);
    if (!name) {
      return;
    }
    const newHero: Hero = { 'id': 0, 'name': name } as Hero;
    this.heroesService.addHero(newHero).subscribe(hero => {
      console.log('GGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG C3B hero= ', hero);
      this.heroes.push(hero);
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
The blocking was listed backend (Symfony4) which refused the pre-query OPTIONS. It was necessary to install and configure the bundle nelmio (https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle) which allows the smooth running of the request.